# Swift include Files

Tags: ios, swift

**CodeAssets.swift**

```
import UIKit
class CodeAssets: NSObject {

func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
    // print("validate calendar: \(testStr)")
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"

    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
 }

}
```

And I have tried to include it like this:

```
import UIKit

class RegisterController: UIViewController, CodeAssets {
```

So I have made a swift class that will store some functions like validation the format of an email string, and I want to include this file in the view so I can use the function but none of the above worked.

I think I am a bit confused coming from the PHP world.

Comment: `And I have tried to include it like this:` That's not how you import or include a file in Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to import the file, just use it like this

```
let objCodeAsset = CodeAssets()
objCodeAsset.isValidEmail(testStr: "abc@gmail.com")
```

In swift you just need to import the Frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use multi-inheritance in swift and you're trying to do this in

```
class RegisterController: UIViewController, CodeAssets
```

if you want to use isValidEmail func, it's better to incompose object of CodeAssets inside RegisterController and call this func from it; like this:

```
class RegisterController: UIViewController {
     var assets = CodeAssets()
}
```